# Airflow: running task t4 even if another has failed in such DAG: t1 >> t2 >> t3 >> t4

Tags: airflow

I've tried to use "trigger_rule" option, but with no success. The problem is that task t3 is not executed when t2 fails (it's intended), so setting "trigger_rule='all_done'" on t4 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add another dummy task between t2 and t3 to trigger if t2 fails and set downstream to t4.  And t4 can be set to trigger if 'one_success' so either the dummy or t3 has to succeed for t4 to be triggered.